# ASP.NET access client side update on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using two listbox for moving items from one to another using jquery. Auto postback is set to false for both the listboxes. 
Is there a way to access the items server side on postback?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is doable using WebMethods. See [this](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/06/aspnet_ajax_invoke_a_static_me.html) By Matt Berseth.

Answer (score 0):

If your moving items clientside, you'll not see the updates to the listbox when you postback because the control is going to use the original viewstate (values when page loaded) during postback.  Your best option is to save the items of the listbox into a hidden field that you can read when you postback the page.  If you just want the selected item, you can get this by using "Request.Form[listbox.ClientID]".

Other posts on the same topic:

[Problem getting list box items added through jquery in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849050/problem-getting-list-box-items-added-through-jquery-in-code-behind)

[Asp.Net ListBox and JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643921/asp-net-listbox-and-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly your ASPX page looks something like:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  ...
  <asp:ListBox ID="listbox1" runat="server">
    ...
  </asp:ListBox>
    ...
  <asp:ListBox ID="listbox2" runat="server">
    ...
  </asp:ListBox>
  ...
</form>
```

You should be able to access the value(s) of your control simply by accessing it's properties on the server-side control in your code-behind class:

For example, if your list box only allows a single item to be selected ([`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) = `ListSelectionMode.Single`):

```
// in ASP.NET code-behind
if (listbox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    string value1 = listbox1.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

Or, it your list box allows multiple items to be selected ([`SelectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.selectionmode.aspx) = `ListSelectionMode.Multiple`):

```
// in ASP.NET code-behind
foreach (ListItem item in listbox1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        // do something with selected item
    }
}
```

Comment: The op mentioned he's using jquery in adding items and wants to read them at server-side,your suggestion won't help since server-side will read the list-box's viewstate,thus won't access those items added by jquery